# Error invalid object name when connectin with node-mssql

Tags: node.js, sql-server-2008-r2, node-mssql

I am using the following code to connect to Ms SQL-Server

```
var node_mssql = require('node-mssql');

/* add configuration to query object */
var queryObj = new node_mssql.Query({
    host: '127.0.0.1',     // You can use 'x.x.x.x\\instance' to connect to named instance 
    port: 1433,
    username: 'myuser',
    password: 'mypwd',
    database: 'persondb'
});

/* set table name to operate */
queryObj.table('dbo.Person');

/* set update query condition */
queryObj.where({
    'FirstName': 'Mathias',
})

/* run update query and fetch response */
queryObj.select(function(results) {
    //  success callback 
    console.log(results);
}, function(err, sql) {
    //  failed callback 
    if(err)
        console.log(err);

    console.log(sql);
});
```

I get the error

```
Invalid object name "undefined.dbo.Person."

Select  * FROM undefined.dbo.Person WHERE FirstName = 'Mathias'
```

It looks like the servername is not picked up. How can I fix this to connect to the Sql-Server?

Comment: Package `node-mssql` is messed and outdated copy of `mssql` module. Just use `mssql` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just typed an incorrect parameter name (`database` instead of `db`):

```
var queryObj = new node_mssql.Query({
    host: '127.0.0.1',     // You can use 'x.x.x.x\\instance' to connect to named instance 
    port: 1433,
    username: 'myuser',
    password: 'mypwd',
    db: 'persondb'
});
```